# Positioning text over layered images

Tags: html, css

I'm creating layered images right now but i need to somehow get text over each layered image. Every time I try adding it, it keeps just sitting next to the image itself. I can't get the positioning down.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 65%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.imageOne {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  left: 35%;
  z-index: 20;
}

.imageThree {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 30;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img class="imageOne" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/380/150/">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="imageTwo" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/260/155/">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="imageThree" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/270/100/">
  </div>
</div>
```

I created a jsfiddle to see what it looks like with the images layered here:

https://jsfiddle.net/k1rpycq2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pseudo-selector to display text over the images, but the div element that contains the image must be of the same width as the image.

Do note that I had to switch the class attribute to the parent div element.

---

[edit] I don't like writing text in CSS so I used a data-attribute instead on the pseudo-element.

```
content: attr(data-caption);
```

```css
#container {
    position: relative;
    /*width: 65%;*/
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.imageOne {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.imageTwo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 20;
}

.imageThree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 30;
}

.imageOne::before,
.imageTwo::before,
.imageThree::before {
    content: attr(data-caption);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);

    font-family: Verdana;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 9px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="imageOne" data-caption="These">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200">
  </div>
  <div class="imageTwo" data-caption="Beautiful">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/80">
  </div>
  <div class="imageThree" data-caption="Images">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow i had no idea you could incorporate the text like this. That's awesome. Thank you so much.
In your opinion, with things being responsive and in this situation, is it okay to use absolute positioning?

Comment: I try to avoid absolute positioning as much as I can, but some occasions forces me to use it. I try to play around with percentage or `vw` instead of pixels for placing elements horizontally, instead of using media-queries. Sometimes, I place absolute elements inside a centered container so there will be more space on either side without hassle.

Comment: I updated the post, where I could remove CSS code, in order to make it more dynamic while making the HTML more intuitive.

Comment: got it. Okay. Well thanks for your help with it. Solved my problem

Comment: Just be aware that the text won't be accessible with this technique and to the best of my knowledge won't be read by screen readers or indexed by search engines. If you want the text to be a part DOM you will need to use a different technique.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is to put the images as background in the targeted div elements using background-image and then positon your text in the div:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<div>
text # 1
</div>
<div>
text # 2
    </div>
<div>
text # 3
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 65%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.imageOne {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image:url(/image1-380x150.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
}

.imageTwo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 66px;
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 20;
    background-image:url(/image2-260x155.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
}
    
.imageThree {
    position: absolute;
    top: 190px;
    left: 10%;
    z-index: 30;
    background-image:url(/image3-270x100.jpg);
    background-size:contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What we need to do here is work with how `position:relative` and `position:absolute` interact. Anything which is `absolute` is positioned `absolutely` in relation to the nearest ancestor with `postition:relative`

Using this, create a bounding div to layer your figures. Then use the `figure` tag with `position:absolute` positioning the `figcaption` within that using `position:absolute`.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 65%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.imageOne {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.imageTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 66px;
  left: 35%;
  z-index: 20;
}

.imageThree {
  position: absolute;
  top: 190px;
  left: 10%;
  z-index: 30;
}

[class^="image"] figure {
  position: relative;
}

[class^="image"] figure>figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="imageOne">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/g/380/150/">
      <figcaption>Bill One</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="imageTwo">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/260/155/">
      <figcaption>Bill Two</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <div class="imageThree">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/270/100/">
      <figcaption>Bill Three</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</div>
```